# heroku + flask importerror "No module named..."

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Hi I have a simple webapp that is running into an ImportError on heroku.

```
2015-03-05T22:25:59.131270+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
2015-03-05T22:25:59.131276+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named requests
2015-03-05T22:25:59.131230+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call  last):
2015-03-05T22:25:59.948813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-05T22:25:59.963418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My requirements.txt was made from `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This is running beautifully in my virtualenv and local.

When I run `heroku run pip freeze`, I see the un-updated:

```
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.10.1
```

but my requirements.txt is:

```
appscript==1.0.1
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.0.1
Flask-Moment==0.4.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-WTF==0.11
gunicorn==19.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.7.0
psutil==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.4.0
requests==2.5.3
six==1.9.0
virtualenv==12.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.6
WTForms==2.0.2
xlwings==0.2.2
```

Everything looks fine when I `git push heroku master` (all imports seem found and installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably take out `xlwings` and `appscript` - the latter only runs on Mac OS and therefore probably causing troubles on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your requirements file is in the root of your application.